# Django file user folder model

Tags: django, model

I would like to know how to create django relation model for user, folder, file

An user can have multiple files and folders.

A folder can have a lot of files but cant have folder int folder

```
class User_t(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    pcw = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    mail = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
    validateMail =  models.BooleanField()
    birthday = models.DateTimeField(max_length=60)
    premium = models.BooleanField()
    premiumEnd = models.DateTimeField(max_length=10)
    totalUpload = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    avatar = models.URLField()

class FileItem(models.Model):
    file_id = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    file_name = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    date_upload = models.DateTimeField(max_length=10)
    data_size = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    key = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    # Django will automatically create owner_id field
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User_t, related_name='files')
    folder = models.ForeignKey('FolderItem', related_name='files')
    # not sure what this (login_accept) is for...
    # login_accept = models.ManyToManyField(User_t)
    file_i = models.FileField(/mnt/test/)

class FolderItem(models.Model):
    folder_id = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    folder_name = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    data_size = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    key = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User_t, related_name='folders')
    # again, not sure what this is for
    # login_accept = models.ManyToManyField(User_t)
```

login_accept is a list of users who can access (have right by the owner) to read (dowload) the file.

I don't know if my way is correct?

Thanks

Comment: Looks fine to me.  It looks like login_accept is a permissions thing, probably the list of users allowed to read and/or write the file or folder.  If you don't care about permissions, leave it out.

Comment: I need to add this feature. 
login_accept = models.ManyToManyField(User_t) 

Please show me the good way to do that

Comment: As far as the data model, just uncomment what you already have.  All this you're doing here is setting up the data model.  You will have to enforce your permissions in your code; it's not something that will happen "magically".